# Absolute beginner, trying to LIMIT & ORDER a DELETE/JOIN query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

I've been handed a MySQL query for deleting millions of entires that I'm trying to add a LIMIT to, which also ORDERS BY ASC. I've little idea what I'm doing, and I'm very stuck.

From what I understand you can't LIMIT a multi-table DELETE, but the solutions I've found that circumvent this issue have been too complicated for me to adapt on my own.

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE d.taxonomy = 'edd_log_type' AND a.post_type = 'edd_log' AND e.term_id = 167
ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 100;
```

Expectation: I'm trying to construct a query that will find and delete the oldest 100 entries. I'm placing a LIMIT because the amount of entries (millions) being worked with time out the query otherwise.

Actual result: syntax errors due to LIMIT not working with multi-table deletes, as far as I understand at least.

Comment: This is a bizarre requirement. Why would you do this?

Comment: @Strawberry The aim is to slowly chip away at these entries from oldest to newest - the limit is to stop the query timing out, since it's working with so many

Comment: I don't get it. If you're just going to 'chip away' at the data set until it's all gone, why not just drop the table?

Comment: @Strawberry There's important information in all of the tables being accessed, but there are also entries within those tables that are useless logs which are bloating the database - as far as I understand, this query targets and deletes those log entries

Comment: In these instances, it's often better to create new tables, retaining only the information you want to keep, then delete/archive the old tables, then rename the new tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use columns related to left joined table in where clause because using where this work as inner join
In these cases  you should move the related  condition in the ON clause

And for deletion (based on your code) you could join you delete statemente with a query that return the 100 id you need

```
  delete a,b,c 
  FROM wp_posts a
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id ) AND d.taxonomy = 'edd_log_type'
  LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id ) AND e.term_id = 167
  INNER JOIN  ( 

      select a.id 
      FROM wp_posts a
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
      LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id ) AND d.taxonomy = 'edd_log_type'
      LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id ) AND e.term_id = 167
      WHERE a.post_type = 'edd_log'
      ORDER BY ID ASC 
      LIMIT 100

  ) t ON t.id = a.id 
  WHERE AND a.post_type = 'edd_log'
```

and as suggested  by Strawberry   for a delete is better  the use of inner join  (you can't delete the rows that don't match  )

```
  delete a,b,c 
  FROM wp_posts a
  INNER  JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
  INNER  JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
  INNER  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id ) AND d.taxonomy = 'edd_log_type'
  INNER  JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id ) AND e.term_id = 167
  INNER JOIN  ( 

      select a.id 
      FROM wp_posts a
      INNER  JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
      INNER  JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
      INNER  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id ) AND d.taxonomy = 'edd_log_type'
      INNER  JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id ) AND e.term_id = 167
      WHERE a.post_type = 'edd_log'
      ORDER BY ID ASC 
      LIMIT 100

  ) t ON t.id = a.id 
  WHERE AND a.post_type = 'edd_log'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your query and received the following error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND a.post_type = 'edd_log'
      ORDER BY ID ASC
      LIMIT 100

  ) t ON' at line 15

Comment: This solution seems to be working, thank you very much for your help!

I'm interested in learning, so I'm curious, why is the following block of query being used twice?
    FROM wp_posts a
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id ) AND d.taxonomy = 'edd_log_type'
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id ) AND e.term_id = 167

Comment: LEFT JOIN on a DELETE ? I'm going to need a *lot* more coffee

Comment: @Strawberry  if you have a little coffee I need it too.  .. answer updated  with your suggestion too